# Error while installing Sugar CRM

Tags: amazon-web-services, sugarcrm

I am installing SugarCRM using sugarcrm-CE-6.4.2-linux-installer.bin file on a AWS ubuntu machine. But, I start getting these errors -

```
Unable to create symbolic link /home/ubuntu/crm/common/bin/captoinfo -> tic
```

What these errors mean? How to solve them? I tried installing using sudo command too.

Answer (score 0):

This says 'tic' is a program that is installed with ncurses.  do you have ncurses?
http://www.scratchbox.org/documentation/user/scratchbox-1.0/html/installdoc.html

if 'tic' did not exist that would be one reason to get the error.